# Cannot install thrift on Suse linux(configure Ok but make failure)

Tags: c++, makefile, thrift, suse

I'm trying to install thrift on SUSE, but encounter some problems.

Runtime Environment:

- SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP1  (x86_64)
- thrift-0.10.0

using the configuration file

```
# ./configure --with-boost=/usr/local/boost-1.59.0 --with-openssl=/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.0a
```

then

```
# make
```

but failed

Error details:

```
……
libtool: compile:  g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../.. -I../../lib/cpp/src/thrift -I../../lib/c_glib/src/thrift -I/usr/local/boost-1.59.0/include -I/usr/local/src/openssl-1.0.0a/include -I./src -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -O2 -std=c++11 -MT src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.lo -MD -MP -MF src/thrift/transport/.deps/TSSLSocket.Tpo -c src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o src/thrift/transport/.libs/TSSLSocket.o
src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp: In constructor 'apache::thrift::transport::SSLContext::SSLContext(const apache::thrift::transport::SSLProtocol&)':

src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp:166:39: error: 'TLSv1_1_method' was not declared in this scope

     ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_1_method());
                                       ^

src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.cpp:168:39: error: 'TLSv1_2_method' was not declared in this scope

     ctx_ = SSL_CTX_new(TLSv1_2_method());
                                       ^

Makefile:1312: recipe for target 'src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.lo' failed

make[3]: *** [src/thrift/transport/TSSLSocket.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/aisp/bak/thrift-0.10.0/lib/cpp'
Makefile:1620: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/aisp/bak/thrift-0.10.0/lib/cpp'
Makefile:635: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/aisp/bak/thrift-0.10.0'
Makefile:548: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I could not find the answer anywhere.
What should I do?

Comment: Do you have `libssl-dev` installed, as per the [requirements](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/)?

Comment: @user657267  It works！I ignore it, thank you!